# Conditionals and git in a bash script

Tags: bash

I use a small bash script to update my git folder (where i clone some projects). I want to add some conditionals to this script.
 I want to add :

> if      [the local branch has been updated]
>
> then      [run something]

The problem is that i have no idea how to let bash understand when the local branch has been updated and when it was already updated

Comment: Maybe you should start reading some basic bash tutorials, there are plenty of them and I'm sure you can arrive to an answer yourself after doing so.

Comment: I don't know the command that is separated from bash. I don't konw if it is a git command or something else.

Comment: You might also want to check out http://githooks.com/

Comment: Maybe there is something that can be useful.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I see two solutions

Both are based on the same commands to get the repo state, but test in a different way.

### First solution

First do a `git remote update > /dev/null` in order to load in git the status of remotes.

Then save the state of you remote in a variable :

```
git_remote_state=$(git status -uno | grep <state wanted> | wc -l)
```

Here, `git status -uno` will give you some info about your remote.

`grep <state wanted>` will parse and find the information you want, the state of the remote: replace `<state wanted>` with `'branch is ahead'`, `'branch is up-to-date'`, or `'branch is behind'` given the state you want.

The `wc -l` part is to get the number of lines, so if you test if the branch is behind, but in fact it's not, `grep` will output nothing and `wc` will count 0 lines. if it was behind, then `grep` will output something (one line), and `wc` will count one line.

That way you can just test on the value, which will be either 0 or 1:

```
if git_remote_state; then
    # git pull...
    # stuff...
fi
```

### Second solution

You still do your `git remote update > /dev/null`, but you parse the state in a different way:

```
get_remote_state=$(git status -uno | grep -oP 'Your branch is \K([\w-]+)')
```

Here, we use the perl regexps to find the state of our branch with a subgroup (refer to this [response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match) if you want more), so here the `git_remote_state` can have three values : `behind`, `up-to-date`, `ahead`.

Then we simply test this value with a case statement:

```
case $git_remote_status in
     behind) #git pull and stuff....
       ;;
     up-to-date | ahead) # echo "nothing to do"...
       ;;
     *) echo "unexpected output, please see 'git status -uno'"
       ;;
esac
```

I think that both have their pros, and cons.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you so much. Tomorrow I will try this and let you know if it works